# Sessions in GA4 not adding up

Tags: google-analytics-4

Ok, do you know why…
the # in Total Sessions and Sessions in default channel group are not adding up here? It shows 3,800 total sessions, but when you add up the channels (organic, direct, etc..) you get 3,837. They used to add up in UA. How can I get an accurate count of all the sessions in my channels?

I tried changing the Session default channel group to other channels and nothing adds up there either

Answer (score 0):

In GA4 session doesn't expire if a user returns to website from the different source in the middle of active session. It would still be one session and both traffic sources would be in the same session.